# How to make unique index constraints on multiple NULLABLE columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I set a unique key index with `NULLABLE` columns, I can insert as many rows as I like:

```
create table routes (
   id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   lastname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   departure DATE DEFAULT NULL,
   returndate DATE DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE KEY uniq (firstname, lastname, departure)
)
```

Why? And more important: how can I keep the unique constraint also on the date columns, although they may be null (and must remain `DATE` type)?

The following sql statement can acutally be executed muliple times:

```
INSERT INTO `routes` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `departure`, `returndate`) 
       VALUES (NULL, 'john', 'doe', NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Can you share the actual data you are inserting?

Comment: Added example above.

Comment: Your unique key definition mentions a column called origin, that doesn't appear in your schema nor example?

Comment: Sorry, just a type, of course it references the existing columns.

Comment: Skip the id column in your INSERT. (Let the dbms handle AUTO_INCREMENT columns.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why? Because `NULL = NULL` is not true.

Uniqueness means it doesn't allow another row to have the same value in a column. But in SQL, NULL compared to any other value — including another NULL — is "unknown." That's how three-valued boolean logic is defined.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique says:

> A UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

What do you expect to happen if you do your INSERT twice? Should it result in a duplicate key conflict even though the "duplicate" is a NULL?

You'll have to create an functional index (available on MySQL 8.0.13 or later):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `routes` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `departure` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `returndate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq` (`firstname`,`lastname`,(coalesce(`departure`, '1900-01-01')))
);

mysql> INSERT INTO `routes` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `departure`, `returndate`) 
    -> VALUES (NULL, 'john', 'doe', NULL, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `routes` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `departure`, `returndate`) 
    ->  VALUES (NULL, 'john', 'doe', NULL, NULL);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'john-doe-1900-01-01' for key 'uniq'
```

Re your comment: No, coalesce() in this functional index doesn't affect the data value stored in the column, it only affects what's *indexed*.

```
mysql> select * from routes;
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+
| id | firstname | lastname | departure | returndate |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | john      | doe      | NULL      | NULL       |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

---

If you use MySQL 5.7+ you can do something similar, but you have to create a virtual column to use for the index:

```
CREATE TABLE `routes` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `departure` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure_notnull` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(`departure`, '1900-01-01')) VIRTUAL,
  `returndate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq` (`firstname`,`lastname`,`departure_notnull`)
)
```

---

If you use MySQL 5.6 or earlier, you can't use virtual columns or functional indexes. You'll have to make the column NOT NULL, and use a special value to signify that it's a non-date.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect multiple inserts resulting in a unique key constraint exception.

Comment: I'm using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27`

Comment: So but isn't `coalesce` nothing different than just using `DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01'`?

Comment: No, coalesce doesn't change the NULL in the column, it indexes the result of an expression instead of the column contents.

Comment: I see, so it would probably be best to upgrade to version 8 in this case...

Comment: There's a ton of other good reasons to upgrade to version 8, this is just one of them! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the database.  Some databases allow duplicate `NULL`s on columns with unique constraints.  Some do not.

One option, of course, is to use a trigger.  That is cumbersom.

Another is to use a default value and leave the column out of any `insert` so the default gets used:

```
create table routes (
   id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   lastname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   departure DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01',
   returndate DATE DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE KEY uniq (firstname, lastname, departure)
);

INSERT INTO `routes` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `returndate`) 
       VALUES ('john', 'doe', NULL);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=900ab29617233c074af3123692dec50c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: AFAIK, Microsoft SQL Server is the only database that makes NULLs conflict in unique keys. This is contrary to the SQL standard.