MySql Index for 2 columns with null value included
I am using MySQL and trying to create an index for 2 columns (name and date)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_date_unique ON `local-db`.device(name, date);

the thing is, date is nullable so null values are not included in the index.
Meaning when I insert: Name = "x" and Date = NULL more than once, it works.
But when I insert: Name = "x" and Date = "2020-1-1" more than once, it gives an error.
How to make it give error with null date as well?

You don't, because that doesn't make sense. Why not, is explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58267967/1427878

Because NULL is an unknown value which is not equal to anything . If my age is unknown and your age is unknown does it means that we are in the same age ?

SQL standard makes exception for null handling in order by and group by clause. Whether null used in unique index is treated as unknown or a special case is opinion based and the decision is vendor specific.

Use functional index or index by virtual generated column. In the index expression replace NULL with some constant but impossible value (use COALESCE). Remember that this index won't be used for queries optimization until the prefix only needed.

Use functional index:
CREATE TABLE device (name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, `date` DATE);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_date_unique ON device (name, (COALESCE(`date`, '1970-01-01')));
INSERT INTO device VALUES ('x', '2020-1-1'), ('x', NULL);

INSERT INTO device VALUES ('x', NULL);


Duplicate entry 'x-1970-01-01' for key 'device.name_date_unique'


INSERT INTO device VALUES ('x', '2020-1-1');


Duplicate entry 'x-2020-01-01' for key 'device.name_date_unique'


fiddle
